# Flutter module with persistent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, flutter

I am trying to achieve a hybrid app with two persistent 'views'. One is a native Android view and the other is a Flutter view.

Using the Add2App / Module approach, I have attempted to achieve this with two fragments, which allows me to either (i) utilise a FlutterFragment directly or (ii) implement a FlutterView inside a normal Android Fragment.

All works fine until I get to device rotation. I utilise onSaveInstanceState, but in every scenario the Flutter fragment/view itself is recreated (taking it back to route '/'), even when trying only to show/hide fragments rather than utilising FragmentManager transactions (add/replace etc).

Ideally I could just lock the hosting Activity's orientation, but I need the Flutter fragment/view to rotate on orientation change.

Is there any way I get the Flutter view to persist on rotation?